# steady-state inductance current

Tags: circuit-analysis

### The question is as follows:

[image]

### **The solution is as follows:**

[image]

### I am confused as to how he just simply made the 20° as the reference instead of 0°! and using the maximum value instead of the rms value which is always used!

Source:
PPI PE Power Reference Manual, 4th Edition – Comprehensive Reference Manual for the Closed-Book NCEES PE Exam

Publisher : PPI, A Kaplan Company; Fourth edition (January 31, 2021)

ISBN-10 : 1591267838

ISBN-13 : 978-1591267836

by John A. Camara PE

Comment: 20° is taken as reference since it's the phase of the source. They simply *rotated the whole system* to align the source to zero and have 'better numbers'. As for the RMS instead of maximum, well, they should have stated it in the answer choices, it's always ambiguos (unless there is some common rule for exercises)

Comment: They took \$\angle 20\$ as the reference, so they got  current with \$\angle -20\$. After obtaining this result, in the final result, they shifted the result by \$\angle 20\$ to get the correct answer. I think the final result would have been the same even without this reference shifting.

Comment: I hate this sloppy way of writing as is done here with the data related to the voltage source: 15cos((10t + 20°).
15-what? 15V, 15kV or 15 m? What is the sum of a time (10t) and and angle (20 °)?
What is the cosine of a time (10t)?
And all that in book which is called a Comprehensive Reference Manual.